# PHP sprintf MySQL query fails with alpha numeric value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query in PHP that works great when the variable is a numeric value but when the variable contains alpha-numeric it throws a "Unknown column 'CC11' in 'where clause'"  I've tried to wrap the %S in quotes but I can't seem to format it correctly?

```
$query_WADAHTG_TechQual = sprintf("SELECT QualID, Skill FROM HTG_TechQual WHERE EmpNumber = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual, "-1"));
```

Comment: What does `GetSQLValueString()` do? What does `$ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query_WADAHTG_TechQual = sprintf("SELECT QualID, Skill FROM HTG_TechQual WHERE EmpNumber = '%s'", GetSQLValueString($ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual, "-1"));
```

In SQL strings must be in `'`

Comment: Okay, I see...I was trying to wrap the whole thing.  Thanks so much for the help!